# How can scrape prices from next pages?

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, python-requests

I'm new to python and web scraping.
I wrote some codes by using requests and beautifulsoup. One code is for scraping prices and names and links. Which works fine and is as follows:

```py
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

urls = "https://www.meisamatr.com/fa/product/cat/2-%D8%A2%D8%B1%D8%A7%DB%8C%D8%B4%DB%8C.html#/pagesize-24/order-new/stock-1/page-1"
source = requests.get(urls).text
soup = BeautifulSoup(source, 'lxml')

for figcaption in soup.find_all('figcaption'):
    price = figcaption.div.text
    name = figcaption.find('a', class_='title').text
    link = figcaption.find('a', class_='title')['href']

    print(price)
    print(name)
    print(link)
```

and also one for making other urls that I need those information scraped from, which also gives the correct urls when I use print():

```py
x = 0
counter = 1

for x in range(0, 70)
    urls = "https://www.meisamatr.com/fa/product/cat/2-%D8%A2%D8%B1%D8%A7%DB%8C%D8%B4%DB%8C.html#/pagesize-24/order-new/stock-1/page-" + str(counter)
    counter += 1
    x += 1
    print(urls)
```

But when I try to combine these two in order to scrape a page and then change url to new one and then scrape it, it just gives the scraped information on the first page 70 times. please guide me through this. the whole code is as follows:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

x = 0
counter = 1
for x in range(0, 70):
    urls = "https://www.meisamatr.com/fa/product/cat/2-%D8%A2%D8%B1%D8%A7%DB%8C%D8%B4%DB%8C.html#/pagesize-24/order-new/stock-1/page-" + str(counter)
    source = requests.get(urls).text
    soup = BeautifulSoup(source, 'lxml')
    counter += 1
    x += 1
    print(urls)

    for figcaption in soup.find_all('figcaption'):
        price = figcaption.div.text
        name = figcaption.find('a', class_='title').text
        link = figcaption.find('a', class_='title')['href']

        print(price)
        print()
        print(name)
        print()
        print(link)
```

Comment: and secondly, the reason you're not getting the other pages is because you don't have it within your for loop.

Comment: I believe I have them in my for loop. Showing codes on the website was confusing. I will try to make it better...

Comment: It is not neccesary to increment `x` as it is the loop variable. Also, `counter` can be removed altogether and simply write `ursl = "......" + str(x+1)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `x=0` and then incriminating it by 1 is redundant and not needed, as you have it iterating through that range `range(0, 70)`. I'm also not sure why you have a `counter` as you don't need that either. Here's how you would do it below:

HOWEVER, I believe that issue is not with the iteration or looping, but the url itself. If you manually go to the two pages as listed below, the content doesn’t change:

```
https://www.meisamatr.com/fa/product/cat/2-%D8%A2%D8%B1%D8%A7%DB%8C%D8%B4%DB%8C.html#/pagesize-24/order-new/stock-1/page-1
```

and then

```
https://www.meisamatr.com/fa/product/cat/2-%D8%A2%D8%B1%D8%A7%DB%8C%D8%B4%DB%8C.html#/pagesize-24/order-new/stock-1/page-2
```

Since the site is dynamic, you'll need to find a different way to iterate page to page, or figure out what the exact url is. So try:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

for x in range(0, 70):
    try:
        urls = 'https://www.meisamatr.com/fa/product/cat/2-%D8%A2%D8%B1%D8%A7%DB%8C%D8%B4%DB%8C.html&pagesize[]=24&order[]=new&stock[]=1&page[]=' +str(x+1) + '&ajax=ok?_=1561559181560'
        source = requests.get(urls).text
        soup = BeautifulSoup(source, 'lxml')

        print('Page: %s' %(x+1))

        for figcaption in soup.find_all('figcaption'):

            price = figcaption.find('span', {'class':'new_price'}).text.strip()
            name = figcaption.find('a', class_='title').text
            link = figcaption.find('a', class_='title')['href']

            print('%s\n%s\n%s' %(price, name, link))
    except:
        break
```

You can find that link by going to the website and looking at the dev tools (Ctrl +Shift+I or right-click 'Inspect') -> network -> XHR

When I did that and then physically click to the next page, I can see how that data was rendered, and found the reference url.

[image]

Comment: Greating coding! thanks. works like a charm. I didn't understand the '&ajax=ok?_=1561559181560' though

Comment: Ah yes. Good question. I’ll answer/address that tomorrow when I get a chance and show where that came from.

Comment: @Noshad70, ok I added in how I found that url for you. Be sure to accept the solution answer as well.